# Programmatically call OnClick method on ASP LinkButton in C#

Tags: c#, webforms

I have this ASP webform with LinkButton

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="LLPIposAttachment.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>iPOS Attachment</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-family: Arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2>iPOS Attachments List</h2>
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="AttachmentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ATTACH_NAME" HeaderText="File Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ATTACH_ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <!-- log part -->
        <asp:Label ID="lbLog" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <!-- log part -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in some specific situations I need to call OnClick method programmatically. The GridView is filled from DB, and when only one line is read I need to call OnClick method automatically.
How to do it in C#? Or it must be done somehow in Javascript or something else?

Comment: When only one line is read from the DB, the page hasn't even rendered yet. Why not share the logic and just call it from there? That is, if there's only one file to download, then just serve it, otherwise, serve the gridview?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Just call the event delegate : `DownloadFile(lnkDownload, EventArgs.Empty);`

**Solution 2:** simulate a click (not very "clean" solution)

This code works for an `asp:Button`.

Use this js function :

```
function eventFire(el, etype) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}
```

In the `onload` js script, run this :

```
var b = document.getElementById(id_button);
eventFire(b, 'click');
```

where `id_button` is `lnkDownload.ClientID`